# Building complex data class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, factory, solid-principles

I have the following builder/factory which abstracts a serializeable model from a class.

```
public class FooBarFactory : IFooBarFactory
{
    public IFooModel Create(IFoo someClass)
    {
        // some complex model building code here
    }
}
```

And I have a concrete implementation of IFooModel like so:

```
public interface IFooModel
{
    string AbstractedData1 { get; }
    string AbstractedData2 { get; }
    int AbstractedData3 { get; }
}

public class ConcreteFooModel : IFooModel
{
    public string AbstractedData1 { get; set; }
    public string AbstractedData2 { get; set; }
    public int AbstractedData3 { get; set; }
    public bool ExtraData1 { get; set; }
}
```

Now arises the issue, I am struggling to find a way to not reference any concrete implementations in my builder/factory method, e.g.

```
public class FooBarFactory : IFooBarFactory
{
    public IFooModel Create(IFoo someClass)
    {
        // some complex model building code here
        var model = new ConcreteFooModel(someClass.data1, someClass.data1); // Aaargh
    }
}
```

Something about this code is smelly to me, perhaps this is the only way, but I don't like the idea of being forced into referencing the concrete implementation to instantiate the data class, IFooModel.

This gets more complex if I now introduce another data holder interface into the IFooModel

```
public interface IFooModel
{
    string AbstractedData1 { get; }
    string AbstractedData2 { get; }
    int AbstractedData3 { get; }
    IBarData BarData { get; }
}

public interface IBarData
{
    // some data in here
}
```

Forcing me then to create another concrete reference for the nested interface

```
public class FooBarFactory : IFooBarFactory
{
    public IFooModel Create(IFoo someClass)
    {
        // some complex model building code here
        IBarData barData = new ConcreteBarData();
        IFooModel model = new ConcreteFooModel(someClass.data1, someClass.data1, barData);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this while still sticking to the SOLID principle and IoC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's important is to look at this from the perspective of the class that depends on `IFooModel` That's probably the first place where you want to prevent coupling.

You can accomplish that by injecting the factory into the class that needs it, like this:

```
public class NeedsFooFactory
{
    private readonly IFooBarFactory _factory;

    public NeedsFooFactory(IFooBarFactory fooBarFactory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void WhatEverThisClassDoes(IFoo foo)
    {
        var fooBar = _factory.Create(foo);
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now the class that depends on the factory is decoupled from any implementation. You can substitute or mock another implementation of the factory that returns a different implementation of `IFooModel`.

Something to stop and think about at this point: Do you need an abstraction for `ConcreteFooModel` at all? If it's just a class that holds data then maybe you don't.

Getting back to the factory: Now that you can replace the factory with any implementation, this becomes less of a concern:

```
public class FooBarFactory : IFooBarFactory
{
    public IFooModel Create(IFoo someClass)
    {
    // some complex model building code here
        IBarData barData = new ConcreteBarData();
        IFooModel model = new ConcreteFooModel(someClass.data1, someClass.data1, barData);
    }
}
```

This implementation of the factory returns a specific concrete implementation of `IFooModel`. Is that bad? At some level classes are going to deal with concrete classes. In this case I think it's okay because this factory is doing what it's supposed to do. You don't have to worry that it's coupled to `ConcreteFooModel`. If you want a class that returns a different implementation you could create a different implementation of `IFooBarFactory` that returns a different implementation of `IFooModel`.

Again, this becomes even less of a concern if you question whether you need an abstraction for your foo model. Quite possibly the concrete class is all you need, and what matters is that you can have different implementations of the factory that populates it.

Comment: Two questions:

**1) "Do you need an abstraction for ConcreteFooModel"**
Probably not, but it's hard to predict future code changes. I am concerned removing the abstraction might back me into a wall later on if I am trying to follow Open/Close principle and make changes.

**2) Factory per concrete implementation**
Isn't a 1:1 ratio a bad design decision (bloatness)? I guess that's more relevant to the factory pattern however, while in this case I'm implementing more of a builder pattern. Although I am unfamiliar with if a 1:1 relationship for the builder pattern is bad or not.

Comment: From the perspective of the consumer, the factory could be a builder. But given the interface in this case, the consumer doesn't know that it's a builder. It just knows that it's asking the factory to return something.